# Bug in Image3D?

Tags: graphics3d, image3d

On a fresh kernel, in an empty notebook, I go directly to the docs of [`Image3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image3D.html) and evaluate one of the Basic Examples:

```
Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"]
  (* or equivalently *)
Image3D @ Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff"]
```

which should give as a result:

[image]

However, I get:

[image]

that is, `Image3D` takes only the first image in the list. Proof:

```
Image3D @ Reverse @ Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff"]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> 10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)

Does anyone witness the same behaviour? **Is it a bug?**

---

**Update:** the same behaviour for `11.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)`.

Comment: `11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)` works like it is supposed to. So perhaps just update if you can.

Comment: works in 10.1 (windows)

Comment: works in `"11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)"`

Comment: Works fine for v10.4.1 for Windows 7.

Comment: Works in `"10.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 8, 2015)"`

Comment: Works in `"11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"`  . windows $10$

Comment: Anyone with v10.4.1 or v11.1.0 under Linux?

Comment: Works in version 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64.